# $f \left(2\sqrt2 \right)-f \left(\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt2} \right)=3$. Is value $1$ in the range of $f(2x)-f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Function $f$ is continous in $\left[\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt2}, 2\sqrt2 \right]$ and we know that
$$f \left(2\sqrt2 \right)-f \left(\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt2} \right)=3.$$

Prove that there is $x$ that $f(2x)-f(x)=1$

> My idea is to make function $g(x) := f(2x) - f(x)$
> and try to prove that it can get values greater and lesser than $1$, and then from Darboux Theorem, I would get that there is $x$ for which $g(x) = 1$.
> But I can't do it. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: consider $g(x)$ for $x=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}},x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $x=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I can't see it. If I add values of $g(x)$ in this three points I get $3$ but i can't see next step.

Comment: It means that at least one of these values is $\leq 1$ and at least one is $\geq 1$.

Comment: aaaaaa, ok I see. Thank you very much. But can they all be equal to $1$? And how did you know what values of $x$ should you put in $g(x)$?

Comment: If one of them is equal to $1$, it's even better. Think about it.